# Swift2 Huge delay in many UIEvents

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, collections

I usually don't ask questions here, but this makes no sense.

After I load and parse a Json (with swiftyjson) I call this methods:

```
 //remove a loadin screen
 uiviewLoader?.removeFromSuperview()
 print("uiview loader removed")

 self.collectionView.reloadData()
 print("refresh table")
```

And thats its.
The thing is, it prints boths msgs (both in emulator and in physical device) but it takes like 15 seconds to see the effects of this lines.

Do I need an extra call??  I have the latest xcode..

Thanks for any tips or advices.

****** More Info ******
I load a json in another class.  when completed loading and parsing, it calls a method in my viewController

```
func jsonParseado(res:Bool){
   print("json result = \(res)")
   if res {
   uiviewLoader?.removeFromSuperView()
   print("loading uiview removed from superview")
   self.collectionView.reloadData() 
   print("refresh data with new values")
   ...
   else{
     ...
   }
```

And after I see the results prints, it takes about 10-15 seconds to remove the loading view and show the collection controller.

Comment: Are you calling `self.collectionView.reloadData()` from a completion handler?

Comment: No.   just trying to remove the uiview.

Comment: Does it behave the same when the device isn't connected to the debugger while you run it?

Comment: Yes.  its the same thing.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question by @MirekE since that IS probably the issue. To clarify: where does the json come from, please show some more code - you probably do some async request to some server to get the json, then parse it -> you are no longer on the main / ui thread and therefore ui updates are delayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. [luk2302](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442804/luk2302) u were right. 
the problem is that Im no longer in the main thread. 
I solve the problem with

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            self.uiviewLoader?.removeFromSuperview()

            print("reload in main thread..")
        } 
//this actually works!!
```

I did load the json with swifty json, wich uses another thread to do so.
but im not sure when I left the main thread...

Thank you all.